# Link fragment bug on android?

Tags: html

Im maintaining a site with the link fragment below. There isnt an element with an ID of top on the page however clicking it still takes you to the top of the page. Is this because the default behavior of any link fragment is to take you to the top of the page?

There is also a weird bug with it on android. It appears multiple times and works the first time but the second time you click it does nothing.

```
<a href="#top">Top</a>
```

Comment: Which android version, which browser and which browser version?

Comment: Im afraid i dont know. Someone showed me on their phone and I wont have access to an android phone for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all undefined anchors take you back to the top of the page.

Comment: It seems like an android bug then.